# Link between combat sports and mental health

Tags: mental-health, sports

Is there evidence to suggest a link between exercising of combat sports and mental health problems (in the later future). For example is there any (reaffirmed) study that shows a higher risk for alzheimer, etc. when the patient done x hours/week of sparring in a full contact combat sport? Professional vs Amateurs?

Comment: I'm not aware of it, and I think it's because the degree of head trauma varies dramatically based on the specific sport, organization, and individuals (e.g. Kung Fu sparring in forms vs MMA brawls).  Perhaps look at the data for boxing, since much of MMA today isn't much different than boxing in body damage, sometimes worse.  I sparred all the time in Kung Fu and never hit my head.  That versus my neighbor who was knocked out regularly in MMA... lots of confounding variables.